# JPEG Creation error in gdal

Tags: python, gdal, linux

Trying to write a 3-band JPEG using gdal_merge but keep getting the following error:

```
Format driver JPEG does not support creation and piecewise writing.
Please select a format that does, such as GTiff (the default) or HFA (Erdas Imagine).
```

I'm not understanding this as on GDAL's [Raster Formats](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html) page the Creation column for JPEG says 'Yes.' Additionally, the JPEG [File Format](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jpeg.html) help page indicates that it is possible to create JPEG.

Here is my command:

```
gdal_merge.py -of JPEG -co QUALITY=90 -co EXIF_THUMBNAIL=YES -n 0 -a_nodata 0 -o /path/to/Output.jpg /path/to/inputs/band1.tif /path/to/inputs/band2.tif /path/to/inputs/band3.tif
```

Why am I recieving this error? I realize that my input bands are 32-bit float but I just figured they would be truncated since JPEG only supports 8-bit. Could this be my problem? I don't want to spend time fixing that if there is something else I'm missing as to why I can't create jpeg.

Comment: I suppose that the message `does not support creation and piecewise writing` is correct and the issue is in piecewise writing that gdal_merge is doing. Write output to GeoTIFF and convert it later to whatever you want. However, for most geospatial needs a tiled GeoTIFF with internal JPEG compression is better choice than JPEG.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you really do need a JPEG output file, not a GeoTIFF with internal JPEG compression...

The [JPEG driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jpeg.html) supports the `CreateCopy` but not the `Create` method. It's not mentioned specifically in the gdal raster [formats list](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html) (and probably should be).  If you check the command line documentation using `gdalinfo` you'll see this.

```
gdalinfo --format JPEG
Format Details:
  Short Name: JPEG
  ...
  Supports: CreateCopy() - Create dataset by copying another.
  ...
```

And for geotiff:

```
gdalinfo --format GTIFF
Format Details:
  Short Name: GTiff
  ...
  Supports: Create() - Create writable dataset.
  Supports: CreateCopy() - Create dataset by copying another.
  ...
```

You need to output to a format like tiff then convert to jpeg with [`gdal_translate`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html).

Alternatively, [`gdalbuildvrt`](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) is a *much* easier way of doing the merge as you don't need to create an intermediate dataset on disk.

```
gdalbuildvrt -separate /path/to/Output.vrt /path/to/inputs/band1.tif /path/to/inputs/band2.tif /path/to/inputs/band3.tif
gdal_translate -of JPEG -scale -ot byte /path/to/Output.vrt /path/to/Output.jpg
```

Comment: You are right, the error does not come from adding new files into the mosaic because the same error happens also with a singe file `gdal_merge.py -of JPEG one.tif out.jpg`.

Comment: gdalbuildvrt is a good solution. I don't know why i didn't think about that. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I'm late to the party and don't have enough reputation to comment on the accepted answer, but I want to add a bonus.  You can avoid the two-step process with the intermediate VRT file by using the `/vsistdout/` and `/vsistdin/` [Virtual File Systems](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_virtual_file_systems.html) and piping the initial command's VRT output to `gdal_translate`.

```
gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:3857 -te -8527009.1 4762026.9 -8526856.3 4762179.7 \
-ts 256 256 -of VRT /imagery/big_image.sid /vsistdout/ | \
gdal_translate -of JPEG /vsistdin/ /tiles/vrt-tile.jpg
```